# Unable to run the code for cozmo using visual studio c# with python

Tags: python-3.x, dialogflow-es

I am unable to run cozmo to play songs. I am using dialogflow to use English to run the cozmo on visual studio c# using python.

Below is my code

```
if (intentName=="onmusic")
    {
        if (parameters["cozmomusic"].ToString() == "music")
        {
            pythonCode += tabs + "\trobot.play_audio(cozmo.audio.AudioEvents.MusicTinyOrchestraStringsMode3)\n";
            //
            pythonCode += tabs + "\trobot.song.SongNote(cozmo.song.NoteTypes.C2, cozmo.song.NoteDurations.Quarter)\n";
            //
            pythonCode += tabs + "\trobot.play_audio(cozmo.audio.AudioEvents.MusicTinyOrchestraBassMode1)\n";

        }
    }
```